# How to have a wxButton destroy itself?

Tags: c++11, wxwidgets

I have a wxButton in my window which I'm `bind`ing with the following:

```
BitmapButton1->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [=](wxCommandEvent& e)
{
    if(TextCtrl1)
        OptionsSizer->Detach(TextCtrl1);
    if(Choice1)
        OptionsSizer->Detach(Choice1);
    if(BitmapButton1)
        OptionsSizer->Detach(BitmapButton1);

    if(TextCtrl1)
        TextCtrl1->Destroy();
    if(Choice1)
        Choice1->Destroy();
    if(BitmapButton1)
        BitmapButton1->Destroy();

    OptionsSizer->Layout();
    OptionsWindow->SetSizer(OptionsSizer);
    SendSizeEvent();

}, bId);
```

The idea is that when the button is clicked it deletes itself as well as a couple of other controls. The above however crashes. I've tried debugging but the debugger seems unable to pick up my breakpoints (something I've found common with wxWidgets).

Comment: I think you should not use `Destroy` on the `control` itself, rather rearrange the controls on the frame/dialog that you want to remain without the control you want to destroy.

Comment: @NeomerArcana, why do you want to destroy it? It might be better to just hide the button and then call Layout() even if you don't intend to show it again.

Answer (score 0):

After the lambda is executed the original pointers will be dangling, with incorrect, not-NULL values. Are they used anywhere else too?
In general, you'd need to provide more info for such a question, like more code, the stack trace, the type of build - you'd obviously need debug build in order to debug it, right?

> the debugger seems unable to pick up my breakpoints (something I've found common with wxWidgets)

There is no such thing as `wxWidgets` preventing the debugger from hitting breakpoints in a debug build. Do make sure you are using the debug build - something I've found common with people with such issues.